# Touchbarserver process running on a non touchbar mac

Tags: macos, catalina, touch-bar

I have a process in the activity monitor named TouchBarServer and it's eating up to 1.5 gb of ram, the problem is I'm using a 2017 macbook pro without a touch bar, so I don't need this process. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: what happens when you restart the Mac? you could also try to force quit the process in activity monitor

Comment: @X_841 the process exists always, and after force quitting it comes back after 2-3 seconds

Comment: I find it eats up a lot of CPU as well.